# Multi tag disambiguation

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

Stack Overflow synonyms only allow you to give a synonym of one tag.
However, in some cases, it would be interesting to have multi-tag synonym to be able to do some disambiguation. Let me give you an example:

- The tag [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) has 6003 questions linked to it.
- Most of the time, it is used to tag question related to the Python library, aka tag [python-multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-multiprocessing). This is the vast majority of the question (4749).
- But sometimes it refers to [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) in another language, such as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). It is only a small number of questions. (89 for Java)

This tag is probably too broad as only few questions are really about [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) in general, but more specific to language implementation of multiple process system.

It would be interesting to be able to indicate that, when there is both tag [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing), the [multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multiprocessing) tag is synonym of [python-multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-multiprocessing). This would help disambiguate the meaning of too broads tags when a specific language tag exists for this concept.

Comment: Just nuke multiprocessing.

Comment: Disagree with Braiam. What needs to be nuked is [python-multiprocessing]. That's already adequately modeled by having the [python] and [multiprocessing] tags together on the same question.